# ¿Alguien me explica como funciona este codigo, para encender y apagar un led?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Bueno este seria el código, lamentablemente solo estoy viendo videos... no tengo una raspberry, por donde vivo tan baratas no son... lo que me confunde aquí es la condicional While, dice mientras sea verdadero... en todo caso cuando veo que ejecuta el código, se enciende y se apaga cada rato el led y no entiendo porque, si le da un valor false, al terminar el while, por lo tanto no debería de volver a ejecutarse o si... se sale de la estructura de control y a mi parecer solo una vez debería de encenderse y y apagarse y nada mas...

```
 import RPi.GPIO
 import time

 RPi.GPIO.setmode(RPi.GPIO.BCM)
 RPi.GPIO.setup(2,RPi.GPIO.OUT)
 While true:
       RPi.GPIO.output(2, True)
       time.sleep(1)
       RPi.GPIO.output(2, False)
       time.sleep(1)
```

En este caso, veo que usa el programa Putty, y no directo desde el Raspbian que lo hace, todavía no se muy bien de esto, pero al siguiente semestre llevare esto y tengo que ir viendo, ya que sera en grupos y económicamente no podre aportar mucho a esto, así que perdón si salto errores muy obvios, solo que por ahora es la única forma que tengo de aprender y la ayuda de ustedes en esta pagina, gracias de antemano a todos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un ciclo infinito, en realidad tal y como lo tienes no es correcto, supongo que simplemente es un error tipográfico ya que debe ser `while True`, a no ser que `true` sea una variable definida previamente.

Un ciclo `while` estará iterando mientras la condición de salida que le sucede sea evaluada como verdadera (`True`). Por lo tanto, por definición un `while True` se estará ejecutando por siempre en condiciones normales a no ser que se rompa internamente el ciclo con un `break`.

La secuencia es por tanto:

1. `RPi.GPIO.setmode(RPi.GPIO.BCM)`: establece que se use el sistema BCM ("Broadcom SOC channel") para la numeración de los pines.
2. `RPi.GPIO.setup(2,RPi.GPIO.OUT)`: se establece el pin 2 como pin de salida.
3. `While True`: como se cumple la condición se entra en el ciclo.
4. `RPi.GPIO.output(2, True)`: se establece el estado del canal como GPIO.HIGH, lo que permite que el pin 2 suministre tensión y enciende el led.
5. `time.sleep(1)`: esperamos un segundo.
6. `RPi.GPIO.output(2, False)`: establecemos el estado del canal en GPIO.LOW y el pin 2 deja de suministrar tensión, led se apaga.
7. `time.sleep(1)`: esperamos otro segundo.
8. Ejecutado el bloque de código contenido en el `while` se vuelve a evaluar la condición de salida del ciclo (paso 3), como sigue siendo cierta se repite todo de nuevo (pasos 4, 5, 6, 7 y 8) y así de forma infinita.

El resultado por tanto será un led que se mantiene encendido por un segundo y luego apagado durante otro segundo repitiéndose este ciclo de forma infinita hasta que el programa sea interrumpido por alguna causa externa al código.

Para entender que hace el ciclo no necesitas la Raspberry, basta con que repliques el código usando `print`:

```
import time

While True:
    print("Led encendido.")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Led apagado")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Por ahí me equivoco, pero no es válido un ciclo infinito en Raspberry Pi? No es la forma de que la placa ejecute el código continuamente??

Answer (score 2):

Si no puedes disponer de una Raspberry Pi, y mientras que la fundación raspberrypi.org no publique el tan ansiado simulador OnLine, existen varias opciones de emulación como [Quemu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/files/) (Del que no puedo opinar ya que no lo he probado), también está el [raspberry-pi-web-simulator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/raspberry-pi-web-simulator/) de Microsoft (lógicamente para su sistema (IoT), del que tampoco puedo opinar), o la [Raspberry Pi Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/) oficial que puedes virtualizar con [Oracle VM VirtualBox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) por ejemplo. Lógicamente estas virtualizaciones no te van a permitir ejecutar ningún código que intente acceder a los GPIO porque sencillamente no están presentes, pero puedes imprimir salidas o enviar datos al log para poder depurar tus códigos. Podrás probar tus códigos y visualizar el escritorio tal cual se vería en una Raspberry Pi original.

Answer (score 1):

Ese `While True` nunca va a terminar porque entra al ciclo cada vez que la condición es verdadera (en este caso la condición es True, y nunca va a cambiar, por ende **siempre** va a ser verdadera), la traducción al "español" del código sería:

```
repetir infinitamente {
    prenderLed();
    esperarUnSegundo();
    apagarLed();
    esperarUnSegundo();
}
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre estructuras de control si seguís teniendo dudas.

Saludos!